# Is it possible to use the past and present tenses in the same sentence?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> I did not complain and **tell** myself to calm down and try to solve this difficult problem.

Or:

> I did not complain and **told** myself to calm down and try to solve this difficult problem.

Some notes:

- I want to mean that I did not complain, and I *did* tell myself to calm down, instead of complaining and not telling myself to calm down.

I don't know whether I should use told or tell in this sentence. Since "complain" is present tense, I should be using "tell", right? But it sounds (to me) weird to be using tell. But if I use "complained" it seems wrong...?

Comment: Is "I did not tell myself to calm down" what you meant? What is the scope of your *not*? Please edit your question to explain. Did you mean to post this to our sister site for [ell.se]?

Comment: 'I did not complain' is _not_ the present tense! The second sentence expresses the meaning you want; it would be clearer with a comma after 'complain'.